# Counter in a selection

Tags: python, odoo

I need to make a method which only counts when selecting the attribute written in the selection "sale", I have always done this function with the attribute itself but never with selection, can someone please help me?

To count in the way that it used to be through the following code, but it does not work because it tells me all the movements, then I require that I count the sales made by a worker and not buy them.

```
def get_sales_made (self):
    for rec in self:
        sales_counter = len (rec.document_ids)
```

I have 3 tables called "type of movement", document "and" worker ", so that I can only count the sales I have to ring" type of movement "with" document "since the latter is a foreign key.
Below is the table with the attributes.

```
class Worker (models.Model):
    _name = 'project_rc.worker'
    sales_counter = fields.Integer (string = "Sales made", compute = "get_sales_made")
    document_ids = fields.One2many (comodel_name = 'project_rc.document', 
    inverse_name = 'worker_id', string = 'Invoice')

    def get_sales_made (self):
        for rec in self:
            sales_counter = len (rec.document_ids.type_movement_id)


class Document (models.Model):
    type_movement_id = fields.Many2one (comodel_name = 'project_rc.type_movement', string = "Movement type")
    worker_id = fields.Many2one (asdel_name = 'project_rc.worker', string = "Worker")
class Type_Movement (models.Model):
    type_movement = fields.Selection ([('purchase', 'Purchase'), ('sale', 'Sale'), ('merma', 'Merma')], string = "Movement type")
    document_ids = fields.One2many (comodel_name = 'project_rc.document', inverse_name = 'type_movimiento_id', string = 'Document')
```

**I used another method to count but it didn't work:**

def get_sales_made (self):

```
      count = self.env ['project_rc.type_movement']. search_count ([('type_movement', '=', 'sale')])

      self.counter_sale = count
```

**view cron**

```
    <record forcecreate = "True" id = "vendor_monthly_counter" model = "ir.cron">

       <field name = "name"> Monthly worker accountant </field>

       <field eval = "True" name = "active" />

       <field name = "user_id" ref = "base.user_root" />

       <field name = "interval_number"> 1 </field>

       <field name = "interval_type"> months </field>

       <field name = "numbercall"> - 1 </field>

       <field ref = "model_proyecto_rc_worker" name = "model_id" />

        <field name = "state"> code </field>

       <field name = "code"> model.get_realized_ sales () </field>

       <field eval = "False" name = "doall" />

       <field name = "function"> True </field>

    </record>

    </data>
```

Comment: Can you share your full code and anything else we might need? See: [mcve].

Comment: All I put there is what I think you may need, since it has the field computed in worker where it will count the sales made by the worker, also add the table "type of movement" with the attribute selection and the key foreign with which he works, and finally the table "document" is not appreciated that contains the table "worker" and "type of movement." To finish with a method that I usually use to count tables with the id but in this case the id is not used but the selection attribute and that is where I need your help.

Comment: update with a more tried method but it didn't work

Comment: Can you provide some test data? Please see: [mcve].

Comment: Example: a worker records a sale or purchase in the document table, it is there that the accountant must count only the sales made and not the purchases, but the type of movement is an attribute of another table that has the same name "movement type" but that table is foreign key to "document"

Comment: I meant like example data that could be used to run and test the program.

Comment: The worker called "Rodrigo" has registered a document, in that document he has the option to choose whether it is a purchase or sale. The worker selected sale. That's where you should start counting the sales made by Rodrigo, since if you make another sale it should increase because you made another sale, then the counter should show a 2. In the case that Rodrigo makes a purchase it should not be counted. Do you understand the process?

Comment: I uploaded an image that demonstrates better what I want to do, with the last added method I get a 1 but I have not made a sale as you can see since they are 4. link photo: https://ibb.co/vs0dw5K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carreful using your function get_sales_made

```
count = self.env ['project_rc.type_movement']. search_count ([('type_movement', '=', 'sale')])
// You're counting the number of TYPES, not the number of DOCUMENTS
self.counter_sale = count
```

What I suppose you want to realise is :

```
@api.depends('document_ids')
def get_sales_made(self):
    for rec in self:
        document = rec.document_ids.filtered(lambda r: r.type_movement_id and r.type_movement_id.type_movement == 'sale')
        rec.sales_counter = len(document)
```

The @api.depends tells Odoo that your field depends on the field document_ids, and will be calculated every time this one is changed.
The filtered funciton catch every document of type 'sale'

Comment: A doubt, in the case that I want to be updated every month as I would have to do?

Comment: If you use the compute method, the field will be calculated everytime it will be displayed in the view
If you want to store a value and update it every month, I suggest to store it without a compute attribute, and then use a cron (https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/odoo/models/ir.cron.html)

Comment: Hello, I added the cron ami vista of the worker since there is the method of accounting for the sales made but it continues to increase with the previous one even though I change the month of sale, perhaps it is automatically updated by default by the system date or tme wrong?. 
I added the cron code used above